# AD B2C custom policy custom claims getting error "Unable to validate the information provided." while signup

Tags: azure, policy, claims

Using Identity Experience Framework and added two custom claims also configured the user inputs.

Changed TrustFrameworkBase based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom and able to view two text fields while signing up.

But after clicking on the "Create" button, getting the error:

> "Unable to validate the information provided."

While signing up, if I am keeping both new fields empty, not getting this error and able to create the user.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i just ran into the same issue, and my solution was that I'm missing the Metadata tags in the "Azure Active Directory" claims provider, so B2C can read/write the extension attributes from the extension store app

```
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">app object id here</Item>
  <Item Key="ClientId">applicationId here</Item>
</Metadata>
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom

IT can either be the "default" extension app or your custom created one.