# Azure B2c error 'Unable to validate the information provided.' when using custom attributes

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to add custom attributes to a custom policy. However it generates this error 'Unable to validate the information provided.'

I followed the documentation of the links below, I have already added application id b2c-extensions-app and object too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Error log message **"Error returned was 400/Request_BadRequest: The following extension properties are not available: extension_f41be....._tipoUsuario."**

Part of the code in my TrustFrameworkExtensions file, where it writes and retrieves the information in AD:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
      <Metadata>
        <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ID here, for example: 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111-->
        <Item Key="5bfd........"></Item>
        <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ObjectId here, for example: 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222-->
        <Item Key="18bd6......."></Item>
      </Metadata>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="client_id">f41be......</Item>
        <!--Insert b2c-extensions-app application ID here, for example: 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111-->
       
      </Metadata>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tipoUsuario"/>
      </PersistedClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!-- Write data during edit profile flow. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId">
     
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tipoUsuario"/>
      </PersistedClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!-- Read data after user authenticates with a local account. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
      
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tipoUsuario" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!-- Read data after user authenticates with a federated account. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
     
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tipoUsuario" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: Did you setup application insights for troubleshooting? Would be great if you can share the relevant log :)
If not, you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights) to setup one.

Comment: Can you please confirm us the metadata url you are using in custom policy

Comment: @Ray I didn't set up the app's insights, do you have this feature?

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity What metadata are you referring to?
I added TechnicalProfile Id = "AAD-Common" to the b2c-extensions-app and object metadata ID.

Following are documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

It informs to insert some more TechnicalProfile, in which also add the same metadata

Comment: i was referring to 
`<Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>

<Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>`

Comment: This usually occurs if you put the wrong IDs in the extensions policy for the Identity Experience Framework and Proxy Identity Experience Frame work applications. As you already confirmed that these are configured correctly wanted to make sure the metadata details. If you are able to share the policy it would be great help to investigate

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity I am using this metadata in my political base
** <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
<Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
<Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
            <Item Key="grant_type">password</Item> **

Comment: @Ray I accessed the logs, a message he’s generating is this "Error returned was 400/Request_BadRequest: The following extension properties are not available: extension_<b2c-extensions-app-guid>_tipoUsuario."

Comment: I edited the question and put part of the configuration that I believe is where the problem is.

Comment: Hi @VictorMoreira, I think you do not need to put client ID metadata (i.e. f41be...) in AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail TechnicalProfile. Your extension attribute should be extension_5bfd..._tipoUsuario, which 5bfd... is your B2C extension App ID.

Comment: @Ray I added the client_id id of the metadata from the b2c extension and it worked.
The only pending problem now is that the custom attribute only comes in the token the first time the user creates and logs in. When he logs out and logs in again, the custom attribute does not come in the token.

Comment: Hi @VictorMoreira, one of the directions is that you can check the RelyingParty of signUp and signIn to see if there is any difference in the returning claims. Moreover, it could be better that you start a new question so that your question can get more attention and help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AD B2C custom policy custom claims getting error "Unable to validate the information provided." while signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530829/ad-b2c-custom-policy-custom-claims-getting-error-unable-to-validate-the-informa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the common root causes to this problem is misconfiguration of client ID metadata of B2C Extension App.

Make sure the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#modify-your-custom-policy) here is followed.

Comment: Yes, make sure to use the client (application) id, not the object id. Also, review the secret or certificate, tenant name and host etc.